# Force Firefox not to change file extension?

Tags: firefox, download, mime-types

Is it possible to force Firefox not to change the file extension of a file the user downloads? Currently I have the problem that I have a .reg file to download, but Firefox, even though in the Download dialog it says "Text file (*.reg)", saves it as a .reg.txt file, which is highly annoying. How to fix this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Can you please share solution, if you have any. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do the following things:

1.) https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file
Maybe extension (in your case .reg) is associated with Notepad and you could changed it in Options/Applications

a) Click the menu button and choose Options.
b) Select the Applications panel.
c) The Applications panel will display. Select the type of file for which you want to change the default action.

2.) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=511624
This is an old bug, but if you use the affected version of firefox...

When you right click on a link to a batch file and click save as, it will allow you to save it, but it automatically adds .txt to the end of the filename without informing you.

You are unable to save it as .bat

Reproducible: Always

Steps to Reproduce:
1.Right click on a batch file link
2.Click save as
3.Save it
Actual Results:
filename is file.bat.txt

Comment: Could you add some content from the links?

Comment: Having a user changing options in the browser is not an option for me. The most recent Firefox is affected by that "bug" by the way.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, Can you please share solution, if you have any. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Firefox on Windows bug. My coworker was implementing download of `.reg` files and I use Firefox, I tested for him and got a `.reg.txt`. Just renaming it after download was sufficient to make the `.reg` work, but I got curious if that would happen on Linux also.

Grabbed my laptop where I have Ubuntu installed and the file was downloaded with the correct extension (just didn't run because `.reg` is a windows extension, it did open in the text editor). It was not automatically renamed as a `.txt`.

Comment: I am on Linux.  I just tried to download [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/%D0%92%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_15_02_2013_avi-iCawTYPtehk.ogv), firefox automatically renamed it to .ogx.  I changed it back to .ogv so I can play the video on my system using default app.